# How do I transfer user (documents, music, etc) files from a replaced windows 10 harddisk

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer, usb-storage

I have replaced the system disk in a laptop with a new SSD and put a clean install of Windows 10 on the laptop.    I have the old harddisk connected ver a converter to a USB port and can see the User Folder.    I wish to copy all documents, music, etc over to the correct folders on the new Windows install.    Clearly, permissions and windows live backup settings, etc need to be correctly setup.   I do not wish to transfer any applications or application settings.

The old harddisk was never connected to windows live and has different account names on the new install.

There must be a better way than doing it by hand…..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't an automatic tool for your case.

In Windows 10, Microsoft has partnered with Laplink to make available the free
[PCmover Express](https://pcmover-10.laplink.com/)
for transferring selected files, folders, and more from the old Windows PC to
a new Windows 10 PC.

Unfortunately, this tool requires having two PCs, the old and new,
both booted and connected via the local network or a Laplink transfer cable.